# Erlang Privilege Separation

Tags: c, security, unix, erlang, privileges

I'm working on an security oriented project based on Erlang. This application needs to access some parts of the system restricted to root or other privileged users. Currently, this project will only work on Unix/Linux/BSD systems and should not alter files (read-only access).

I've thought (and tested) some of these solutions, but, I don't know what should I take with Erlang. What is the worst? What is the best? What is the easiest to maintain?

Thanks!

### 1 node (as root)

This solution is the worst, and, I want to avoid it even on testing servers.

```
 _____________________________
|                             |
| (root)                      |
|  ___________      _______   |
| |           |    |       |  |
| | Erlang VM |<---| Files |  |
| |___________|    |_______|  |
|_____________________________|
```

You can see here a big picture of what I don't currently want.

```erlang
#!/usr/bin/env escript
main([]) ->
  ok;
main([H|T]) ->
  {ok, Data} = file:read_file(H),
  io:format("~p: ~p~n", [H,Data]),
  main(T).
```

Run it as root, and voilà.

```sh
su - root
${script_path}/readfile.escript /etc/shadow
```

### 1 node (as root) + 1 node (as restricted user)

I need to start 2 nodes, one running as root or with another privileged user and one other running node with restricted users, easily accessible from outside world. This method work pretty well but has many issue. Firstly, I can't connect to privileged user node with standard Erlang distributed protocol due to remote procedure call between connected nodes (restricted node can execute arbitrary commands on privileged node). I don't know if Erlang can actually filter RPC before executing them. Secondly, I need to manage two nodes on one host.

```
 ________________             ____________________________
|                |           |                            |
| (r_user)       |           | (root)                     |
|  ___________   |           |  ___________      _______  |
| |           |  |           | |           |    |       | |
| | Erlang VM |<===[socket]===>| Erlang VM |<---| Files | |
| |___________|  |           | |___________|    |_______| |
|________________|           |____________________________|
```

In following examples, I will start two Erlang shell. The first shell will be in restricted mode:

```sh
su - myuser
erl -sname restricted -cookie ${mycookie}
```

The second one will run with a privileged user:

```sh
su - root
erl -sname privileged -cookie ${mycookie}
```

#### Standard Erlang RPC (not enough security)

Finally, on restricted node (via shell for this example), I can have access to all files:

```erlang
{ok, Data} = rpc:call(privileged, file, read_file, ["/etc/shadow"]).
```

#### With "Firewall" Method

> I'm using local unix socket in this example, supported only until R19/R20.
>   Restricted user need to have access to this socket, stored somewhere in
>   `/var/run`.

### 1 node (as restricted user) + external commands (with sudo)

I give the right to Erlang VM process to execute commands with sudo. I just need to execute specific program, get stdout and parse it. In this case, I need to use existing available programs from my system or create a new one.

```
 ________________            _______________________
|                |          |                       |
| (r_user)       |          | (root)                |
|  ___________   |          |  ______      _______  |
| |           |  |          | |      |    |       | |
| | Erlang VM |<===[stdin]===>| sudo |<---| Files | |
| |___________|  |          | |______|    |_______| |
|________________|          |_______________________|
```

### 1 node (as restricted user) + ports (setuid)

I create a ports set with setuid flag. This program has now right to read from files but, I need to place it in secure place on the server. If I want to make it dynamic, I should also define a strict protocol between Erlang VM and this ports. IMO, setuid is rarely a good answer.

```
 ________________            ________________________
|                |          |                        |
| (r_user)       |          | (root)   [setuid]      |
|  ___________   |          |  _______/     _______  |
| |           |  |          | |       |    |       | |
| | Erlang VM |<===[stdin]===>| ports |<---| Files | |
| |___________|  |          | |_______|    |_______| |
|________________|          |________________________|
```

### 1 node (as restricted user) + NIF

I don't think I can give specific right to a NIF inside Erlang VM, maybe with capsicum or other non-portable/OS-specific kernel features.

```
 _______________
|               |
| (r_user)      |
|  ___________  |
| |           | |
| | Erlang VM | |
| |___________| |
| |           | |
| | NIF       | |
| |___________| |   _______
| |           | |  |       |
| | ???       |<---| Files |
| |___________| |  |_______|
|_______________|
```

### 1 node (as restricted user) + 1 daemon (as root)

I can create a daemon running as root, connected to Erlang VM with an Unix Socket or another methods. This solution is a bit like ports or external command with sudo, except I need to manage a long living daemon with privilege.

```
 ________________            _________________________
|                |          |                         |
| (r_user)       |          | (root)                  |
|  ___________   |          |  ________      _______  |
| |           |  |          | |        |    |       | |
| | Erlang VM |<===[socket]==>| daemon |<---| Files | |
| |___________|  |          | |________|    |_______| |
|________________|          |_________________________|
```

### Custom Erlang VM

[OpenSSH and lot of other secure software](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/papers/privsep.pdf) runs as root and create 2 interconnected process with pipes. When starting Erlang VM as root, 2 processes are spawned, one as root, and another in restricted user. When some action require root privilege, restricted process send a request to root process and wait for its answer. I guess its the more complex solution currently, and I don't master enough C and Erlang VM to make this thing working well.

```
 ______________            _______________
|              |          |               |
| (root)       |          | (r_user)      |
|  __________  |          |  ___________  |
| |          | |          | |           | |
| | PrivProc |<===[pipe]===>| Erlang VM | |
| |__________| |          | |___________| |
|______________|          |_______________|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From security perspective your best option is to minimise the amount and complexity of code running with root privileges. So I would rule out all the options when you run a whole Erlang VM as root - there's simply too much code there to lock it down safely.

As long as you only need to read some files, the best option would be to write a small C program that you run from the Erlang VM with `sudo`. All this program has to do is to open the file for you and hand over the file descriptor to the Erlang process via a Unix socket. I used to work on a project that relied on this technique to open privileged TCP ports, and it worked like a charm. Unfortunately that wasn't an open source project, but with some googling I found this library that does exactly the same thing: https://github.com/msantos/procket

I'd advise you to fork `procket` and strip down it a bit (you don't seem to need `icmp` support, only regular files opened in read-only mode).

Once you have the file descriptor in the Erlang VM, you can read from it in different ways:

- Using a NIF like `procket:read/2` does.
- Access the file descriptor as an Erlang port, see the [network sniffing example](https://github.com/msantos/procket#sniff-the-network) in the `procket` docs.